# Modal targetting same id, regardless of which user I click

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, modal-dialog

I have a standard forloop which populates a table. In the table I have a button called remove permission which populates a modal. This modal is targetting the first user, no matter which user I click on. The infomration displays just fine for each user in the table, but I get this issue for the modal.

Here is the code

```
    <tbody>
    @foreach($administrators as $administrator)
        <tr class="rowlink user_info_{!! $administrator->id!!}">
            <td>{!! $administrator->username !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $administrator->name !!}</td>
            <td><a class="maillink" href="{!! url("mailto:".$administrator->email)!!}">{!! $administrator->email !!}</a></td>
            <td>{!! $administrator->user_ip !!}</td>

            <td>
                @if($administrator->confirmed==1)
                    <label class="label label-success">Yes</label>
                @else
                    <label class="label label-danger">No</label>
                @endif
            </td>

            <td>SuperAdmin</td>
            <td class="visible-lg">{!! $administrator->created_at !!}</td>
            <td class="visible-lg">{!! $administrator->id !!}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:;" data-user='{!! $administrator->id !!}'
                   data-toggle="modal"
                   data-target="#remove_permission"
                   data-accent="alert"
                   class="atrium-button--text remove_superadmin_btn">
                   <svg width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18"><use xlink:href="#icon-delete"></use></svg>
                   <span>Remove Permission</span>
                 </a>


                <a href="{!! route('superadmins.view', $administrator->id) !!}"
                   data-accent="positive"
                   class="atrium-button--text">

                   <svg width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18"><use xlink:href="#icon-arrow"></use></svg>
                   <span>View & Edit</span>
                 </a>

                <a data-accent="primary"
                  class="atrium-button--text"
                  href="{!! route('admin.account.confirm.resend', $administrator->id) !!}">

                  <svg width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18"><use xlink:href="#icon-edit"></use></svg>
                  <span>Send Email</span>
                </a>

                <a data-accent="yellow"
                  class="atrium-button--text"
                  href="#javascript:;">

                  <svg width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18"><use xlink:href="#icon-flag"></use></svg>
                  <span>Password Help</span>
                </a>


                <div id="remove_permission" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Remove Permission</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                              <p>Are you sure you want to remove the super-admin permissions from {{ $administrator->id }}</p></br>

                                <form action="/admin/admin/superadmins/remove/{{ $administrator->id}}" method="POST">
                                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                                  {{ method_field('PUT') }}

                                  <button type="submit" class="atrium-button">
                                    <svg width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18"><use xlink:href="#icon-check"></use></svg>
                                    <span>Remove Permission</span>
                                  </button>

                                  <a class="atrium-button--subtle" data-accent="alert" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    <svg width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18"><use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use></svg>
                                    <span>Cancel</span>
                                  </a>

                                </form>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have multiple models but all of them have same ID, which is resulting is the last ID to be taken by the modal.

Change the modal link and model code like this

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-user='{!! $administrator->id !!}'
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#remove_permission_{{$administrator->id}}"
  data-accent="alert"
  class="atrium-button--text remove_superadmin_btn">
  <svg width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18"><use xlink:href="#icon-delete"> 
  </use</svg>
  <span>Remove Permission</span>
</a>
```

Modal:

```
<div id="remove_permission_{{$administrator->id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Remove Permission</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to remove the super-admin permissions from {{ $administrator->id }}</p></br>

        <form action="/admin/admin/superadmins/remove/{{ $administrator->id}}" method="POST">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          {{ method_field('PUT') }}

          <button type="submit" class="atrium-button">
            <svg width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18"><use xlink:href="#icon-check"></use></svg>
            <span>Remove Permission</span>
          </button>

          <a class="atrium-button--subtle" data-accent="alert" data-dismiss="modal">
            <svg width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18"><use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use></svg>
            <span>Cancel</span>
          </a>

        </form>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```